# How to ignore non numeric values in a formula Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm writing this case statement, in my SQL code, but if the values in the columns: "pp.fee" and "exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE" is anything other than numeric value, this code fails, kindly tell how to make this code fail proof for any time of values in the above mentioned columns:

```
    CASE exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT
        WHEN 'FALSE' THEN pp.fee
        WHEN 'TRUE' THEN pp.fee - ( pp.fee * (exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE/100))
    END AS Annual_Tuition_Fees_in_Local_Currency
FROM
```

Comment: Hi - how do you expect to do a numeric calculation using non-numeric data? What result are you expecting where there is non-numeric data? I know this is not strictly what you asked, but the “correct” solution is to fix your data/data model - not try to fix your calculations because your data makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

The simple case is to use the [TRY_TO_type](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html) for the data type you are wanting, then if it is that type, you get the number, otherwise you get a null.

```
CASE exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT
    WHEN 'FALSE' THEN try_to_number(pp.fee)
    WHEN 'TRUE' THEN try_to_number(pp.fee) - ( try_to_number(pp.fee) * (try_to_number(exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE)/100))
END AS Annual_Tuition_Fees_in_Local_Currency
```

as an aside, if you are using floating point, you should for numerical stability do you multiples first, then you division:

```
CASE exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT
    WHEN 'FALSE' THEN try_to_number(pp.fee)
    WHEN 'TRUE' THEN try_to_number(pp.fee) - ( try_to_number(pp.fee) * try_to_number(exp_pg_partners.DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE) /100)
END AS Annual_Tuition_Fees_in_Local_Currency
```

Comment: I tried both of the above codes, and it is giving the same error:
"SQL compilation error: Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types FLOAT and NUMBER(38,0)"

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly af, but you can cast them all to string and then go from there to number (it will be null if it's a garbage input)

example:

```
    WHEN 'FALSE' THEN try_to_number(pp.fee::STRING)
```